# The convergence of endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\{A_i\}$ is a sequence in the endomorphism of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $e^{A_i}$ converges to $e^A$, then can we conclude that $A_i$ converges to $A$?

Comment: Hint: In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349180/if-ea-and-eb-commute-do-a-and-b-commute/349186#349186) you will find many examples of matrices $A$ such that $e^A = I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For $n>1$, the matrix exponential function is not injective on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Therefore there exist $A\neq B$ such that $e^A=e^B$. Take $A_i=B$ for all $i$, you get a counterexample. For instance, take $A=0$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&-2\pi\\ 2\pi&0}$. Then $e^A=e^B=I$. For $n=2$, see a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338426/conditions-under-which-real-matrix-exponential-are-equivalent).